# Disable voiceover feedback on UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiaccessibility

I'm currently implementing accessibility for my game. I'm using UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction for the buttons of the interface, as suggested by Apple. It works well, but the problem is that you have to touch every button of the interface once, to 'activate' it. It makes sense, as the blind people have to go through all the elements of the interface before they can use it. 
However, I'm using the same interface again and again in the game, I'd like to disable voiceover if the user has already discovered the interface in that game session. (that'll probably be an option that you can enable/disable in the game settings).
Can you think of any way to do that?

Comment: you can try… make a "Bool" to check the "plaing game".. if the user has already played .. you can try:  if (gamePlayed.on)
    yourButtonElement.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraitNotEnabled;

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. The voiceover still announces the name of the button once before you can start to use it. I can't find any accessibility trait that does what I want, and it looks like I'm going to have to find a 'hack'